# Run Service only when on Wifi if user wants to

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I made an app whos purpose is to download and set wallpaper in set intervals.

User can choose to do that only when connected to wifi or not.

Relevant code:

```
 mWallpaperButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mSwitchWifi.isChecked()) {
                    mConnectivity = mConnectionDetector.isConnectedToWifi();
                } else {
                    mConnectivity = mConnectionDetector.isConnectedToInternet();
                }

                if (mConnectivity) { 
                my code here
                }
```

The code above works fine for setting the wallpaper the first time.

My problem is, I need the Service to check if the user wants to update wallpaper only over WIFI before doing so. At the moment, wallpaper is updated regardless of `mSwitchWifi` state. (which is bad, because it can use mobile data and user sometimes doesn't want that.)

I tried running similar Switch code in Service but I can't because it must be called in a UI Thread.

I also tried couple of workarounds and `Intent.putExtra` but I get exception:

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference
```

Any idea how to check network state in service?

My service code atm:

```
public static class Service extends IntentService {
    public Service() {
        super("wallpaperchanger-download");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (url == null) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String getUrl = sharedPreferences.getString(pref_urlKey, null);
            if (getUrl != null) {
                url = getUrl;
            }
        }

        wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

        try {
            InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
            Log.v(TAG, url);
            wm.setStream(input);
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        loading = false;
        Log.v(TAG, "Service Running Url " + url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you question is how to access the user selection inside a service/runnable/thread then you can use shared preferences to achieve this. So in your case when the user selects the choice for the first time you want to do something like this:

```
if(mSwitchWifi.isChecked()) { // i guess this is no wifi 

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sharedPeredences.edit()
    editor.putBoolean("isWifi", false) 

} else { // guessing this is wifi 

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sharedPeredences.edit()
    editor.putBoolean("isWifi", true)
}
```

This is this code to check if it is true or false:

```
mWallpaperButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Boolean isWifi = isWifi()

            if (!isWifi) { // i guess this is if not wifi


                mConnectivity = mConnectionDetector.isConnectedToWifi();

            } else if (isWifi) { // guessing this is wifi

                mConnectivity = mConnectionDetector.isConnectedToInternet();
            }
        }
}

public Boolean isWifi() { // you can call this inside your service

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean wifiState = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isWifi", true)

    return wifiState;

}
```

This is just a very rough implementation to give an idea of how you can do it, you can improve this many ways. For example you could put the if statement thats inside the onClickListener in the isWifi() function and just call isWifi() inside your runnable/thread...

Comment: I get the idea, I guess my implantation didn't work because I was thinking that I don't need to save a single Boolean in SharedPreferences. Gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

you can set list preferences to auto update functions based on the network ....
You can create separate class to check the connectivity and from that class you can select the preferences like auto update only on wifi or when connected to network or do not auto update ....